# Stop nuget from updating Binding redirect for one package

Tags: c#, nuget, assembly-binding-redirect

I'm using Nuget and would like to keep the automatic binding redirects.
However for one specific assembly I would like to stop nuget from applying an automatic redirect during package restore.

Is this possible?

As far as I know I can only disable it on project level, but not on referenced assembly level.

Background:
System.Net.Http 4.1.1.0 has a bug so I need to keep it at 4.0.0.0 although some packages say they want 4.1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue on github, so I guess the answer is "no": https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/9910